# Difficulties with an ambiguous sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

> 新しく首相に就任した安倍晋三氏は、その著書『美しい国へ』（文春新書）において次のようなことを書いている。人は、自分が育った郷土に対して素朴な愛着をもつが、それはどこからくるのだろうか。それは、その国の歴史や伝統、文化などに接しているうちにはぐくまれてきたものである。だから「自らが帰属する国がつむいできた歴史や伝統、また文化に誇りをもちたいと思うのは、だれがなんといおうと、本来、ごく自然の感情なのである」。
>
> 確かに、人は、自分が育った郷土に対して素朴な愛情をもつ。しかし、それがそのまま自然に国を愛する気持ちになるかというと、必ずしもそうはいえない。特に、現代の若い世代にとって、「国を愛する」ということが、「だれがなんといおうと、ごく自然の感情である」というほど自明である、というとかなり心もとないのではなかろうか。
>
> では、「国を愛する」とはどういうことか。どこからでてくることなのか。実は、その後で、安倍氏自身、その答えを書いている。それは、たとえば、外国に行くとすぐにわかることだ。外国人はただ外国語がうまいというだけでは心を開いてくれない。外国人がわれわれに関心を持つのは、ただ抽象的な個人ではなく、その人間の正体、つまり、彼の帰属する国に、彼が背負っている歴史や伝統や文化に関心を持っているのである。
>
> その通りであって、私というものの正体（Who am  I?）を見せなければ、外国人と真のコミューニケーションはできない。そして「私は誰か（Who?）」を構成する無視し得ない要素が、彼が帰属する「国」なのである。**さらにいえば、この場は誰か」「私はどこに帰属するのか」と問われば、「国」という要素は意識にのぼらない。**「国を愛する」ということは決して自然で自明とわけではないのであって、いってみれば、一種の倫理的な要素、あるいは決断という要素を含んでいる

This is the whole passage for context , but I'm basically confused about the sentence beginning with さらにいえば.

Essentially, to me it seems the author is trying to say that a person's country is a vital component of the question of who someone is, and a requirement for communication with foreigners.

The part that I don't really get is what he means by "「この場は誰か」「私はどこに帰属するのか」と問われば", because first of all, ｢この場は誰か」makes little sense to me due to its ambiguity ('This place is who?' / 'This place is whose'? / 'From now, who?'), and none of the potential meanings I can see actually fit the idea that "country is not something that you would think of as a component".

Secondly, I'm not sure who is actually asking these questions, or if they are actual questions and not 'constructions' like the above ｢私は誰か？」. Does he mean "you wouldn't think of country as an element in the construction of 'where do I belong'? That to me seems weird, because I would imagine it is an element that people would think of...

Comment: Is it the whole text? It seems that something should come before the first sentence...

Comment: @broccoliforest the whole text is pretty long, I felt like that would be reasonable for context, but I'll add everything that comes before that.

Comment: この場は誰か is strange and makes no sense to me either.. and what follows この場 doesn't fit well with what precedes it..  It feels as if a few lines were skipped between この場 and は誰か... Is that from a book? or magazine or newspaper? (Are you sure there's no left corner bracket `「` between `さらにいえば、` and `この場`?) Can you upload a photo?

Comment: And 問われば is ungrammatical by itself. It's probably a typo for 問われなければ. Maybe the original text is severely broken for some reason?

Comment: ^ あ～・・　「『私はどこに帰属するのか』と**問われなければ** 、『国』という要素は意識にのぼらない。」ってことね・・　I first thought it was a typo or error of 問われれば, but 問われなければ would probably make more sense..

Comment: @chocolate It's from a translation assignment from my university, so I don't have the original text. I'm assuming it was just scanned by OCR or something stupid like that, resulting in these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Those questions are actual questions. Well, more like hypothetical questions to be asked to (young? Japanese) people. The concept of *country* does not come to mind for those people when asked those questions. It sounds like you might be conflating your own view of the situation (that country is an element that people would think of when asked "*what do I belong to*") with what the author is saying:

> 「国を愛する」ということは決して自然で自明とわけではないのであって

"Loving one's country" is definitely not something that is naturally self-evident.

Comment: Fair point. Do you have any opinion about what question ｢この場は誰か」is actually asking?

Comment: @Ciaran Honestly, it's pretty confusing, but I think based on context it means "what/who is this place?"